# How can I calculate $g(m)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+m}{m}\right]^{-1}$?

Tags: calculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

How can I calculate the following?

$$g(m)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+m}{m}\right]^{-1}$$

Also I need to know what mean this results, for example $g(0)=2, g(1)\approx1,38629=\ln(4), g(2)\approx1,22741=4-2\ln(4)$. I know only this three results and two of them by lucky guess.

If I made some mistakes, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} = 2^n$, so you have

$$\eqalign{ g(m) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} {n+m \choose m}^{-1} = {}_2F_{1}(1,1; m+1; 1/2)\cr &= 2 m\; LerchPhi(-1,1,m)\cr
&= m (\Psi((m+1)/2) - \Psi(m/2))} $$

In particular, the first few values are
$$ \eqalign{g(1) &= 2 \ln(2)\cr
g(2) &= 4-4 \ln(2)\cr
g(3) &= -3+6 \ln(2)\cr
g(4) &= 20/3-8 \ln(2)\cr
g(5) &= -35/6+10 \ln(2)\cr
g(6) &= 47/5-12 \ln(2)\cr
g(7) &= -259/30+14 \ln(2)\cr
g(8) &= 1276/105-16 \ln(2)\cr
g(9) &= -1599/140+18 \ln(2)\cr
g(10) &= 1879/126-20 \ln(2)\cr
}$$